# find directories with specific patterns leads to Permission denied error and no result

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have this kind of shell script on Linux:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Please enter directory pattern: "
read dirs
find $dirs > /tmp/justbay.txt


allDirs=$(find $dirs ! -readable -prune)
echo $allDirs
lines=$($allDirs | wc -l)
echo $lines

if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "Directory not found"
 exit 1
fi

echo $alldirs
```

I know I can do something like: `>/dev/null 2>&1` but this question is not about error message, as it seems line count is always 0 no matter directory exists or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you cannot exec `$allDirs`.  Probably you wanted to do as follows:

```
lines=$(echo "$allDirs" | wc -l)
```

But in this version `$allDirs` gets expanded in one line so you will always get 1 for `$lines`.

The most simple solution is to pipe the output from `find` directly to `wc`:

```
lines=$(find "$dirs" ! -readable -prune | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems with your code.

The first one is that the `find` utility does not take a **pattern** as its first argument, it takes a single path.

If you want to iterate over a number of directories, then execute the `find` in a loop like this:

```
for dir in $pattern; do
    find $dir ...
done
```

The second one is that you try to execute the contents of the `$allDirs` variable when you do `$($allDirs | wc -l)`. You probably wanted something like `$( echo $allDirs | wc -l )`, depending on what your intention with that particular line was.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 problems with your script.

1. You should use the `-name` option
2. Rather than saving the list of directories in a variable and then doing `wc -l` later on, do it one step as suggested by @yaegashi.
3. When you want to `echo` the `$alldirs` variable, use `quotes` so that the `*` in the directory names do not get expanded.

So, your `find` command coupled with `wc` would look something like this:

```
find -name "*$dir*" ! -readable -prune 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

This should work just fine, even for directories which have an asterisk (`*`) in their names.

Your final script would read something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Please enter directory pattern: "
read dirs
find $dirs > /tmp/justbay.txt

$alldirs=$(find -name "*$dir*" ! -readable -prune 2>/dev/null)
$lines=$(find -name "*$dir*" ! -readable -prune 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
 echo "Directory not found"
 exit 1
fi

echo "$alldirs" #Quoting is important, otherwise the asterisk may get expanded
```